# Apache's mod_dir keeps redirecting to wrong Port

Tags: apache-2.2, haproxy, varnish

I have a setup with a HAProxy in front of a Varnish cache who requests an Apache2 server.

The Apache is listening on an internal IP on Port 12345 and is configured with `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort Off` to prevent the spilling of that internal-use-only Port. I have also tested different combinations of `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort` and `UseCanonicalName` with `On` and `Off`. However, despite those canonical directives, Apache2 seems to have problems when receiving a request for a directory without a trailing slash:

```
UCPP: On, UCN: Not set:
Request:  https://www.example.org/test-page
Response: Redirect(301) to http://www.example.org:12345/test-page/

UCPP: On, UCN: On
Request:  https://www.example.org/test-page
Response: Redirect(301) to https://www.example.org:12345/test-page/


UCPP: Off, UCN: Off
Request:  https://www.example.org/test-page
Response: Redirect(301) without Location header
```

This of course won't work, as this port is only internal. The site is running a Joomla, which works fine with this setup, just those folders which would get a redirect from mod_dir don't seem to work. My Apache configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.150.100:12345>
    ServerName www.example.org

    UseCanonicalPhysicalPort Off
    UseCanonicalName On

    <Directory "/var/www/www.example.org">
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way to prevent those redirects? Best would be to prevent those wrong redirects inside Apache, but I'd be open to configuration changes to Varnish or HAProxy.

*Note:* Please don't suggest to use port 80, as I have more than one port on Apache used by varnish(a workaround to get VHosts working better) and thus this is no option.

Answer (score 0):

A URL for a directory without a trailing slash is not the canonical URL for this resource, this is why **mod_dir** redirects the user.  This is a general W3C recommendation.

The redirection with your custom port is probably happening because your HAproxy or Varnish is creating a new HTTP request that is being sent to Apache.  Your apache receives the very first request with the `12345` port already present.  This is why the `UseCanonicalName` and `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort` seem to be ineffective.

But you can prevent apache from sending a redirect by setting the **mod_dir** `DirectorySlash` directive to `Off`.

If `test-page` is actually an existing directory on your file system, this should work fine.